# At what airport will Australian advance passenger processing (APP) be performed?

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, australia, check-in

Assume a passenger flies Zurich-Dubai-Sydney-Nouméa on a single e-ticket, and checks in on the Qantas website.

Then assume the following two scenarios:

1. The passenger prints the boarding passes at home and goes directly to the gate, **or**
2. The passenger collects the boarding passes at Zurich airport.

In each scenario, will Australian APP processing take place in Zurich or Dubai, and at what exact stage of the check-in/boarding process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL/DR:** You should expect APP to be completed at check-in for all flights which means in Zurich.

More...

You can read all about it here: [Advance Passenger Processing](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/Busi/Air/APP)

Some notable points:

- All documentation is written with the term 'at check-in' which means a Boarding Pass should not be issued unless OK TO BOARD is returned.
- Nearly all carriers, especially single carriers such as QF on this itinerary, will check you in for all segments.
- Barring some very edge cases, the airline has no interest in boarding you for one segment when you would not be allowed to fly any following segment.
- It's likely that Qantas would need to verify, either by scanning or an Agent, your Passport details once so if you haven't flows Qantas on that Passport before, you may be required to check in at the airport.  This is perfectly normal and doesn't indicate any problem on it's own.
- As these are all international segments, you should expect to show your travel docs every time you board.
- (For the nitpickers ;) There are some scenarios alluded to in the manual that could allow a traveler to fly ZRH-DXB, then be denied boarding DXB-SYD.  There is however no chance of flying DXB-SYD without APP responsibility.

This Answer is based on experience with the big Western Hemishpere travel schemes and I have no reason to think Australia approaches this much differently.  I've had to read all of these guides and they're only as specific as they need to be and don't attempt to address every conceivable scenario, that's what the phone number or telex is for.  If any Member who works for QF or BOC provides a more detailed answer, I'm happy to remove this one.

Comment: I'm perfectly familiar with the manual, but the person concerned has an unusual case, and knowing the check-in staff at ZRH, they will probably not want to let the traveller board even though she's actually perfectly fine to fly. The relevant section in the manual is 2.10.5, paragraph 3, being that the person (no, not me) only holds a Swedish identity card (which is valid for New Caledonia) and, having lost their passport thrice within 3 years, cannot get a new one.

Comment: Essentially what I want to establish is which handling agent - that at ZRH or at DXB - I need to contact to clear this up with in advance (in addition to contacting New Caledonian police to sort out a Timatic error)

Comment: @Coke Wow, that was exactly the 'scenario eluded to' I was referring.  When an override for no docs is needed.  Because of point #2, I can't imagine QF in ZRH allowing boarding unless it can be resolved there.  There's really nothing they could do in DXB then can't in ZRH since QF is responsible for both stations.  Realistically, it depends on weather ZRH accepts the Swedish card as a valid travel doc and proof of Swedish Citizenship.

Comment: @Coke Actually, seems you biggest problem is that Timatic says a Passport is required to enter New Caledonia for Swedish nationals.  Even when originating from ZRH with no transits.  Feel free to try yourself: https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC

Comment: Correct, because Timatic's programmed to state that EU IDs are only valid for Pacific French territories when arriving from other Pacific French territories (try putting French Polynesia as the origin). Which is an error, as I found out from the Polynesian police a while ago, so I'm going to call the New Caledonians and ask them to send IATA an update request. That's out of scope though.

Comment: @Coke Hope it works out, but until Timatic is updated, she's not going anywhere even if you are Jean-Yves Le Drian himself :)

Comment: I of all people should know, having faced that very issue in Turkey when boarding a flight to Italy :D Yeah, we're not booking anything until Timatic's been updated

Comment: Australia requires airlines to do a face-to-face passport check as part of APP (see slide 10 of [this presentation](https://www.icao.int/Meetings/TRIP-Symposium-2017/Presentations/FRANZI.pdf)).  This will either be done at the check-in desk or at the gate (if the passenger was able to print a boarding pass online and does not have checked luggage).